# How to let spark skip failed task

Tags: apache-spark

Our HDFS contains some malformed data. It fails my Spark job at the very beginning `context.newAPIHadoopFile()`, where there is no way to catch the exception and move on.

In MapReduce, there is a cure for this `mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent`. Is there a similar setting in Spark?

**Edit:**

I found this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10781 .. It seems like not supported. Any suggestions of workaround are greatly appreciated.